# Add playlist Items dynamically in MediaElement Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

Currently I am able to add media items to playlist using static HTML code by using mep-feture-playlist plug-in.

```
<video id="player" controls="controls" poster="media/poster.jpg" width="540" height="400">
    <Source src="media/video1.mp4" title="video1" type="video/mp4"></Source>
    <Source src="media/flashMovie.flv" title="Flash File" type="video/flv"></Source>
</video>
```

However,  I want to add playlist items dynamically either using jquery or javascript. I have JSON object with media src and type.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your starting DOM

```
<video id="player" controls="controls" poster="media/poster.jpg" width="540" height="400"></video>
```

And then you can append the json to this DOM object

```
var someJson = [
    {
        'media_src': 'http://www.test.com/movie.mp4',
        'type': 'video/mp4',
        'title': 'mp4'
    },
    {
        'media_src': 'http://www.test.com/movie.flv',
        'type': 'video/flv',
        'title': 'flv'
    },
    {
        'media_src': 'http://www.test.com/movie.ogg',
        'type': 'video/ogg',
        'title': 'flv'
    }
];

// create an object that you can clone and add data to
var sourceObject = $('<source />');

// iterate thru the json
$.each(someJson, function (index_someJson, value_someJson) {

    // clone the original object
    var thisSourceObject = sourceObject.clone();

    // give it attributes based on the json item
    thisSourceObject.attr({
        'src': value_someJson.media_src,
        'type': value_someJson.type,
        'title': value_someJson.title
    });

    // append this to the '#player' element
    $('#player').append(thisSourceObject);

})

console.log($('#player')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery .append http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
jQuery("#player").append("<Source src=\"media/newfile.flv\" title=\"new title\" type=\"video/flv\"></Source>");
```

For a JSON object, you can use a forEach loop to help build this HTML for an append statement.